# Azure Pipeline error which updating PowerBI Datasource

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to update PowerBI datasource using Powershell in Azure devops Pipeline. This works sometimes and sometimes I get an error :
##[error]System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

The command on which I get this error is :

```
$urlUpdateDatasource = [string]::Format("groups/{0}/datasets/{1}/Default.UpdateDatasources", $GroupID, $destinationDataset.Id);
            $body= "{
                                    ""updateDetails"": [
                                        {
                                        ""datasourceSelector"": {
                                            ""datasourceType"": ""$srcDBType"",
                                            ""connectionDetails"": {
                                            ""server"": ""$srcServer"",
                                            ""database"": ""$srcDB""
                                            }
                                        },
                                        ""connectionDetails"": {
                                            ""server"": ""$destinationServer"",
                                            ""database"": ""$destinationDB""
                                        }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                    }"
            Write-Host  $body
            Write-Host   $urlUpdateDatasource

            try{
               $updateDS = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $urlUpdateDatasource  -Method Post -Body $body
               }
            catch{
               Write-Host  'Failed to UpdateDatasources $_'  
            }
```

I have observed that when this step takes for than 1.5 min. I get this error though the update is successful . SO this error is false and shows my pipeline as failed even though it is not. Please suggest how I can handle this.

Comment: Perhaps the default timeout for ```Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod``` is 90 seconds? You could try adding a longer value with the ```-TimeoutSec``` parameter - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/invoke-powerbirestmethod?view=powerbi-ps - and see if that helps any...

Comment: Ah, in fact the default value is 100 seconds - see https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/src/Modules/Profile/Commands.Profile/help/Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod.md#-timeoutsec

Comment: Thank you ... I changed the timeout to 500 sec and now getting error "##[error]System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)."

Comment: @Piyush Do you have the same issue if you run your powershell script locally?

Comment: I cannot install in QA environment locally so was not able to try it